# Serialization omitting nulls

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have a class like this:

```
@Serializable
data class MyClass(
    val prop1: Int,
    val prop2: Int?
)
```

When prop2 is null, I want to serialize this class without including the prop2 property. I can do this like this:

```
val json = Json { explicitNulls = false }
json.encodeToString(MyClass(42, null))  // gives {"prop1": 42}
```

Unfortunately, there are many places in a large project that serialize this class, and currently they just use `Json.encodeToString` which includes the nulls explicitly.

How can I enforce the serialization of this class to not serialize nulls? I need this to apply just to this class; other serializable classes in the project need to continue to have explicit nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can give the selected fields a default of `null`, then you can use the [EncodeDefault annotation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-encode-default/index.html):

```
@Serializable
data class MyClass(
    val prop1: Int,
    @EncodeDefault(NEVER) val prop2: Int? = null
)
```

This will avoid encoding `prop2` if it is null, irrespective of the setting of the `encodeDefaults` property of the Json serializer you use when you serialize your class instance.

Comment: can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)

Comment: @Klitos how can set @EncodeDefault(NEVER) to class instead of property ?

Comment: @Vencat unfortunately it's not possible (as far as I understand), as the annotation only works on properties.